# Event click no funciona cuando sobre textview en holder de RecyclerView Android-studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Problemas con evento click recyclerView en Android Studio.

Me gustaría capturar el evento de clic en cada tarjeta de recyclerView, pero hasta ahora solo me funciona cuando hago clic en la imagen o en las áreas fuera de la vista de texto.

Les comparto fragmentos del código de mi progreso, ¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

---

***Fragment: Este es el fragment que estoy usando para bindear el recyclerview, estoy usando viewBiinding***

```
   //method onViewCreated
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        setupRecyclerView()
        viewModelHome.fetchList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when (it) {
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    binding.progressbarHome.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }

                is Resource.Success -> {
                    binding.progressbarHome.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.rvHomeList.adapter = HomeAdapter(requireContext(), it.data, object : HomeAdapter.onItemListClickLister{
                        override fun onItemClick(drink: Drink) {
                            val bundle = Bundle()
                            bundle.putParcelable("drink", drink)
                            findNavController().navigate(R.id.detalleHomeFragment, bundle)
                        }
                    })

                }

                is Resource.Failure -> {
                    binding.progressbarHome.visibility = View.GONE
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Ocurrio un error al traer los datos: ${it.exception}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }
        })

    }

private fun setupRecyclerView() {

        binding.rvHomeList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        binding.rvHomeList.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(requireContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))

    }
```

---

***Adapter:*** En esta clase extiende de de RecyclerView.Adapter por medio de una clase abstracta,

```
    class HomeAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val listDrink: List<Drink>,
    private val onItemClickListener: onItemListClickLister
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<*>>() {

    private var listDrinkAdapter = listOf<Drink>()

    interface onItemListClickLister {
        fun onItemClick(drink: Drink)
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder<*> {

        val itemBinding = FragmentHomeRecyclerViewListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
        val holder = MainViewHolder(itemBinding)

        return holder
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = listDrink.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<*>, position: Int) {
      
        when (holder) {
            is MainViewHolder ->  {
                 /*holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                     onItemClickListener.onItemClick(listDrink[position])
                 }*/

                holder.bind(listDrink[position], position)
            }
        }

    }

    
    inner class MainViewHolder(
        val viewListAdapter: FragmentHomeRecyclerViewListBinding
    ) : BaseViewHolder<Drink>(viewListAdapter.root) {

        
        override fun bind(item: Drink, position: Int) {

            Glide.with(context).load(item.imagen).centerCrop()
                .into(viewListAdapter.imgRecyclerViewHome)

            viewListAdapter.tvRecylerViewHomeTittle.text =
                item.nombreCocktail

            viewListAdapter.tvRecylerViewHomeDescription.text =
                item.descripcion

            //viewListAdapter.setOnClickListener { onItemClickListener.onItemClick(item) }
            //viewListAdapter.root.setOnClickListener { onItemClickListener.onItemClick(item) }
            viewListAdapter.containerRvHome.setOnClickListener {onItemClickListener.onItemClick(item)}


        }

    }

}
```

---

***Abstract BaseViewHolder:: recibe la vista que se infla en el metodo onCreateViewHolder***

```
abstract class BaseViewHolder<T>(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    abstract fun bind(item: T, position: Int)
}
```

***Block de codigo xml, contiene el diseño para cada holder del recyclerView***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container_rv_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="#CDCDCD">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_recyclerView_home"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_recylerView_home_tittle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            tools:text="Titulo"
            android:tooltipText="Titulo"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:background="#9C9C9C"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_recyclerView_home"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img_recyclerView_home" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_recylerView_home_description"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#9C9C9C"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            tools:text="Qewrw werwe werwe rwer wer wejlfakjsk  afkajs pwoe3rjkds l ajsdflka  sdjf 39sw sdlfka askdfjal jwel fjaklsdf l sdjfiao 34234 laj faskdf lk3423 4l fal sdfjaslkdfj 234  lk324j q23j4q 34 lfrae faas 23l4j23l4 ."
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:tooltipText="Descripcion"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_recylerView_home_tittle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_recylerView_home_tittle"
             />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

[image: Desing Xml]

[image: RecyclerView]